# Having trouble importing tails signing key. Cannot find Import Key (Default)

Tags: tails, help, onion-routing, error

Earlier today I had attempted to download tails but the signing key seems to not register an import key or PGP Keys. I am running windows 10 and have downloaded the tails iso. **The problem is when attempting to open the signing key it does not automatically prompt me to use Import Key and is a key file instead of PGP Keys.**

Comment: What operating system are you currently using?

Comment: Aspire E 15 Windows 10

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you have actually downloaded GnuPG from gpg4win.org Once you have installed Gpg (or if you already have) you should be able to right click on the Key file (which is the way a PGP key should be recognized) and see an item called `More GpgEX options`. From that menu you should have the option to `Import keys` thats how it used to work on Windows. https://tails.boum.org/download/index.en.html#download.verify-the-iso-image-using-other-operating-systems This is a link to the tails website, where they give verification instructions for Windows users.